How to Implement a Custom Calculator in ASE for a System with Two Particle Types?
I'm new to ASE and currently working on a simulation involving two types of particles, A and B, with quantities NA and NB respectively, within a simulation box of dimensions (4,4,4) in x, y, and z directions. These particles interact via specific forces:
Particle A experiences a force composed of -kx, Langevin force, and another LJ force.
Particle B experiences only the LJ force.
I'm seeking guidance on implementing a custom calculator in ASE to handle these interactions. Are there any existing examples or resources that demonstrate how to create similar calculators? Additionally, I'd like feedback on whether the following script outline would be suitable for this task:
import ase
from ase import units
import numpy as np
from ase import Atoms
from ase.md.velocitydistribution import MaxwellBoltzmannDistribution
from ase.md.langevin import Langevin
from ase import io

atoms=io.read('geometry.xyz') # xyz file containing the geometry

atoms.set_cell((4, 4, 4))
atoms.set_pbc(True)

atoms.calc = # use my custom calculator
MaxwellBoltzmannDistribution(atoms, temperature)
dyn.langevin(atoms, timestep, temperature, gamma)

# post processing (e. g. dyn.attach())
dyn.run(some time step)

Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

+1. Welcome to our community.

for calculators, does this help as a reference? https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/blob/master/ase/calculators/lj.py?ref_type=heads
